# Ubuntu Studio nvidia driver not loading after update

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors

Can see several posts around the net that looks similar, but have tried a few solutions and no luck.
I have had Ubuntu Studio 20.04 for a while and it ran flawlessly, then an update last night including kernel, a reboot then my Nvidia not working, only one monitor working (have 2) and that is stuck in 1024x768 (usually 1920x1080).
The monitor not working is hdmi.
Had been running 440 driver, now a new option has appeared under ‘additional drivers’ of ‘440-server’ which seems to be the preferred one. Spent a few hours trying to fix this last night then gave up and did a fresh install.
Install was fine and both monitors and nvidia was working, then software updater did its thing again, reboot and then back to one monitor and Nvidia not working. Starting Xserver comes up with an empty box (eventually, takes a minute or two).

I also have Xubuntu 20.04 on another drive which also had a big software update last night, that went through fine and am using it now to post this. My (noob) guess is some incompatibility between the nvidia driver and the latest low-latency kernal, is my thinking at the moment..

Any help would be appreciated, my Ubuntu Studio is now usable now and I really would like to be able to fix it…

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my GTX 1050 Ti and Ubuntu Studio 20.04.
I now, after two months using Nouveau, got it working: I installed the "nvidia-driver-435" through the GUI and **then** installed the corresponding "linux-modules-nvidia-435-lowlatency" package using the terminal. Rebooted the system and the resolution was 1440p as expected.

Of course, it would be great if it would install this package automatically!